# Circular Dependency in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to make a new column in Power BI for z-scores for average Player Load per week however my data set doesn't have a variable for week so I created that and then I created the Player Load Average per Week measure but now when I try to do the z-score column it says there's a circular dependency. So I was wondering if there's another way I can do this to calculate the z scores for the whole week. Here is what I have done so far. I appreciate any help.

```
WeekStart = 'Catapult'[Date] - WEEKDAY('Catapult'[Date],2) +1
```

```
Avg PL per Week =
AVERAGEX(
   KEEPFILTERS(VALUES(Catapult[WeekStart])),
   CALCULATE(SUM('Catapult'[Total Player Load]))   
)
```

```
Z-Score =
VAR _athlete = 'Catapult'[Player Name]
VAR _today = 'Catapult'[Avg PL per Week]
VAR _average =
   AVERAGEX(
       KEEPFILTERS(VALUES(Catapult[WeekStart])),
       CALCULATE(SUM('Catapult'[Avg PL per Week]))
   )
VAR _sd =
   STDEVX.P(
       KEEPFILTERS(VALUES(Catapult[WeekStart])),
       CALCULATE(SUM('Catapult'[Avg PL per Week]))
   )
RETURN
```

Answer (score 1):

WeekStart should be a calculated column, as it apparently is.  But Avg PL per Week should be a measure.

Calculated columns are calculated and materialized at model refresh time, so can be used in measures.